# how to use multiple select statements in stored procedure as columns in Resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which has multiple sql statments,

```
SELECT X,ID FROM TABLE1
SELECT Y,ID FROM TABLE2 
SELECT Z,ID FROM Table3
```

WHEN I EXECUTE the above statements form procedure
My result set should be

[image]

ID, X,Y,Z will the columns and 1,10,20,30 will be the values of 1st row , 6, 40, 50, 60 will be the values of second row, ... goes on
I am using SQL SERVER 2005

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: is there only one line in each table?

Comment: @Twelft yes, it will have only one line for now.

Comment: The answer is yes...you do a cross join.  select x,y,z from table1,table2,table3 should actually work (horrible syntax, but it works).  When you have multiple lines in these tables though, you are going to get 'cross joins', meaning you need some method of relating the data.  if table1 has 3 rows, 10,11,12 and table2 has 3 rows of 20,21,22 and table 3 is one row, you are going to get 9 results (one for each combination of 10,11,12 and 20,21,22).  It might be best to explain what you are trying to achieve here and why this is the output you want

Comment: @Twelfth in first case I am getting values based on condition like where DeptID = 100 then in that case I will have only line(record) but when I have no condition it will will have more lines (one for each department) then in that case I need to display results department wise in which department will be a column.

Comment: Many rows require a 'common' column to link them on (in sql, they are referred to as keys).  If you are using department id, then you'd want to start using more standard joins.  select deptid,x,y,z from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.dept id = t2.deptid inner join table3 t3 on t3.deptid = t1.deptid.  This will list results by department.  Remember you want to relate data from different tables on keys

Comment: @Twelfth the select queries are independent to one another & they have their own logic, can't join them.Is there any alternate way ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's only 1 row in each table you can just do the following:

```
select
    (select X from table1) X,
    (select Y from table2) Y,
    (select Z from table3) Z;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91d4d/2)

For your second example, you can merely use `join`:

```
select
    t1.id,
    t1.X,
    t2.Y,
    t3.Z
from
    table1 t1
        inner join
    table2 t2
        on t1.id = t2.id
        inner join
    table t3
        on t2.id = t3.id;
```

If the tables are really place holders for much larger queries, it might read more easily to use `with`

```
;with t1 as (
    select id, X from table1
), t2 as (
    select id, Y from table2,
), t3 as (
    select id, Z from table3
) select
    t1.id,
    t1.X,
    t2.Y,
    t3.Z
from
    t1
        inner join
    t2
        on t1.id = t2.id
        inner join
    t3
        on t2.id = t3.id;
```

Comment: it's working with one row, how to match rows when it has more than one row. ?

Comment: Probably best to change the question to include multiple rows. Maybe more specific table names would help.

Comment: I modified the question.

Comment: it's working as expected.. thank you..!!! I have never done this kind of query/joins, is there any specific method/approach used I can read some material regarding it..

Comment: I'm sure if you google for `sql join tutorial` it will come up with stuff.